# Login Form API Response Code

Tags: javascript, html, rest, http, protocols

I'm creating an API endpoint for a mobile app and for computer web browsers. Both devices use the same API endpoint with a POST request sent to /users/session for authentication. The mobile phone requires a 200 Status Code response. However, as login forms do, I need to redirect browsers to the home logged in page where the user can see their information. Do I return a 301 subsequently after? What is the best practice to implement this?

In summary: I need to use the same API endpoint for mobile and computer, but am unsure how to redirect while returning a 200 Status Code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a 200 OK is the proper code to return upon successful login. This makes the API more generic and doesn't tie it to any particular use (mobile vs desktop). You might try placing the redirect logic in the desktop site itself and use ajax to submit the data. This will give you more flexibility for handling login errors as well. This is a basic example with [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/users/session",
   data: loginForm,
   success: function(){
     //Redirect user to home page
     window.location.replace("/home");
   },
   dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this while still returning a JSON response? i.e. 
{"result": "fail", "reason" : "no matching username"}

Comment: read the documentation for the ajax fail method $.ajax({fail(function(response) {
    alert( "error: " + response.responseText );
  }});

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax(serverUrl, {
   type: "POST",
   data: dataToSave,
   statusCode: {
      200: function (response) {
         alert('200');
      },
      201: function (response) {
         alert('201');
      }
   }, success: function () {
      alert('1');
   },
});
```